# Drag and Drop not working using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop

I am trying to drag a text into another text using Selenium WebDriver but it's not working. I tried all the solutions which I can find but none of the solutions are working. I observe the clickAndHold is getting performed but moveToElement and dropping of the element is not happening.It is identifying the text to be dragged and holding it but for some reason it is not moving the text and dropping it to the desired location. Tried with different menthods and xpath as well. PFB the methods that i tried:

METHOD 1:

```
     public void DragAndDrop(String ObjectName, String OtherElement)
             {
                         WebElement ActionObject = GetObject(ObjectName); 
                          WebElement DropObject = GetObject(OtherElement);
    
             
             if(ActionObject.isDisplayed() && DropObject.isDisplayed()) {
             if(GetBrowserInfo().startsWith("IE")) MoveToObject(ActionObject); 
    {
            Actions builder = new Actions(driver); 
            
         Actions dragAndDrop = (Actions)builder.clickAndHold(ActionObject).dragAndDrop(ActionObject,DropObject).build()
             dragAndDrop.perform();
             }
```

METHOD 2:

```
public void DragAndDrop(String ObjectName, String OtherElement) 
         { 
               try {
         WebElement ActionObject = GetObject(ObjectName); 
         WebElement DropObject = GetObject(OtherElement);
         
         if(ActionObject.isEnabled() && ActionObject.isDisplayed()) 
         {
         if(GetBrowserInfo().startsWith("IE")) MoveToObject(ActionObject); 
         try {
         Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
         
         Action dragDrop = builder.dragAndDrop(ActionObject, DropObject).build();
         dragDrop.perform();
         }
```

METHOD 3:

```
public void DragAndDrop(String ObjectName, String OtherElement) { try {
         WebElement ActionObject = GetObject(ObjectName); WebElement DropObject =
         GetObject(OtherElement);
         
         if(ActionObject.isDisplayed() && DropObject.isDisplayed()) {
         if(GetBrowserInfo().startsWith("IE")) MoveToObject(ActionObject); try {
         
         Thread.sleep(3000); JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
         
         js.executeScript("function createEvent(typeOfEvent) {\n" +
         "var event =document.createEvent(\"CustomEvent\");\n" +
         "event.initCustomEvent(typeOfEvent,true, true, null);\n" +
         "event.dataTransfer = {\n" + "data: {},\n" +
         "setData: function (key, value) {\n" + "this.data[key] = value;\n" + "},\n" +
         "getData: function (key) {\n" + "return this.data[key];\n" + "}\n" + "};\n" +
         "return event;\n" + "}\n" + "\n" +
         "function dispatchEvent(element, event,transferData) {\n" +
         "if (transferData !== undefined) {\n" +
         "event.dataTransfer = transferData;\n" + "}\n" +
         "if (element.dispatchEvent) {\n" + "element.dispatchEvent(event);\n" +
         "} else if (element.fireEvent) {\n" +
         "element.fireEvent(\"on\" + event.type, event);\n" + "}\n" + "}\n" + "\n" +
         "function simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(element, destination) {\n" +
         "var dragStartEvent =createEvent('dragstart');\n" +
         "dispatchEvent(element, dragStartEvent);\n" +
         "var dropEvent = createEvent('drop');\n" +
         "dispatchEvent(destination, dropEvent,dragStartEvent.dataTransfer);\n" +
         "var dragEndEvent = createEvent('dragend');\n" +
         "dispatchEvent(element, dragEndEvent,dropEvent.dataTransfer);\n" + "}\n" +
         "\n" + "var source = arguments[0];\n" + "var destination = arguments[1];\n" +
         "simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(source,destination);", ActionObject, DropObject);
         
         }
```

METHOD 4:

```
public void DragAndDrop(String a, String b) 
{ try {
         WebElement a = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("your_selector")); //
         WebElement b = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("your_selector"));
         
int x = b.getLocation().x; int y = b.getLocation().y;
         
         Actions actions = new Actions(driver); actions.moveToElement(a)
         .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1)) .clickAndHold(a) .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
         .moveByOffset(x, y) .moveToElement(b) .moveByOffset(x,y)
         .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1)) .release().build().perform(); 
       } catch (Exception e) { Environment.loger.log(Level.ERROR,"Exception occured"); }
```

METHOD 5:

```
builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)  .click(ActionObject)
         .dragAndDrop(element, DropObject)  .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL);  Action
         selected = builder.build(); selected.perform(); 
 } 
         }
```

None of the above methods are working. All the above runs without any error but drag and drop is not happening in the application.I am using chrome browser. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Try `builder.clickAndHold(fromElement)
.moveToElement(toElement)
.release(toElement)
.build();`. source:[How to drag and drop in Selenium - BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/drag-and-drop-in-selenium).

Comment: I tried using the mentioned method as well but it is still not working. It is clicking and holding the target element but not moving the element to the destination. @AliasCartellano